# Clicking on "load more" button via puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I am new to JS. I need to parse comments from Instagram, but first I need to load them all. I am using Puppeteer in Node.js, so I wrote this code:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    while(document.querySelector('main').querySelector('ul').querySelector('button'))
      document.querySelector('main').querySelector('ul').querySelector('button').click()
  })
```

It does nothing and starts an endless loop. I tried to make a timeout inside the loop and so on...
I expect that code will check if this button exists and if true - click() on it while it exists loading more and more comments.
I can't catch what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to a question very similar to this one here:
[Puppeteer / Node.js to click a button as long as it exists -- and when it no longer exists, commence action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200857/puppeteer-node-js-to-click-a-button-as-long-as-it-exists-and-when-it-no-lon)

You should be able to apply it to finding and continually clicking on your "load more" button.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Am I right writing like that because I get 'undefind'


`const loadMoreButton = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('main').querySelector('ul').querySelector('button');
  })` ?

Comment: I would suggest you use a cleaner CSS selector. For example you don't need to query for `main`, then for `ul`, then for `button`. Depending on the layout of your DOM, you might be able to do something simpler such as `ul li button` (assuming the button is inside a list element in your unordered list). Keep everything clean and simple. Don't over-complicate it. If you want, post a snapshot of your DOM and which button you're trying to find and then we can all help you find a simpler selector.

Comment: I tried with `const loadMoreButton = '.class'` and it works perfectly, thanks! But I 
 need to access though dom elements because instagram often changes its classes

Comment: If classes are changing (and I'm aware a number of sites do this) then what you need to do is find a unique part of the selector that never changes. For example, on that button the class might be `2xP123_button` today but `3rQ456_button` next month: note that the `_button` part of the class stays the same all of the time. So you can have a selector like this: `button[class*="_button"]` to indicate that you want to find that button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a using a [`while()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop, you can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to slow down each iteration to a more manageable pace while you load the comments:

```
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const button = document.querySelector('main ul button');
      if (button !== null) {
        button.click();
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve();
      }
    }, 100);
  });
});
```