# Puppeteer Scroll in Div and Click Button and do this untill the Bottom

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer

Im new to Puppeteer and Nodejs and Im trying on scrolling inside this Modal and after every 10 accounts there comes a Show More Results Button. Now what I want to achieve is that I get the href property of every account(which im currently able to for first 10 which showup by default) and then hit the Button and get the next 10 and keep on doing it for untill all the accounts are done.
Any Help will be Appreciated.
Cudos!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23lYN.png)
This is the button Im trying to click coz it loads new list, what i aim on doing is to scroll through this entire list while getting the hrefs of all the people, but since this button wont open in chromium and also im unable to click on it.
Any Suggestions on how i can achieve this task. Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check this answer, might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200857/puppeteer-node-js-to-click-a-button-as-long-as-it-exists-and-when-it-no-lon

Comment: If modal is a part of the html page, then no problem, you can click on modal button just like any other button. Just try to grab modal button id, name or class.

Comment: i have added the image in the post after editing i hope you can see it if not please to comment below actually im new to stackoverflow so i dont really know how it works and how to picture to the comment

Comment: `await page.click("button[id='ember689']");  ` This code will click on the button.

Comment: but the problem is that the button id changes everytime the page reloads

Comment: `await page.click('div[class="social-details-reactors-tab-body"] > button'); `    Maybe you can try this?

Comment: Thank You so much for your help. Got it work!!

Comment: Can you review this? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613068) @Abdulhakim